# Retrieving passed String Array elements - Android

Tags: android, arrays, string, bundle, argument-passing

I believe I am passing a String array from Class A to Class B correctly, however I am having a bit of trouble accessing each element individually. Here is a general view of my code.

```
String[] inputArr = new String[4];
//CLASS A=====================================          
inputArr[0] = zero;
inputArr[1] = one;
inputArr[2] = two;
inputArr[3] = three;

Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putStringArray("input",inputArr);

//CLASSB==================================================
Bundle bundle = this.getIntent().getExtras();
String[] myStrings = new String[4];
myStrings = bundle.getStringArray("input");
```

So if this is correctly getting passed, then how would I go about assigning indivdual strings in Class B to the elements in the passed array? I have tried:

```
String aStr = myStrings[0];
```

However, this is showing the error message - "syntax error on token ";", Expression expected after this token."  Is this the wrong method to use in this situation? If so, what should I be using? Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: Ok, thank you, these methods works as well. It turns out, I was actually being careless and had a non-related logic error further back in my code resulting in the posted problem. Thank you for your help, and sorry for posting too rapidly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
String[] myStrings = getIntent().getStringArray("input");
```

Answer (score 1):

**Incase of Class A**

```
i.putExtra("input",inputArr);
```

**In case of Class B**

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
int arrayB = extras.getStringArray("numbers");
```